# create a cycle without repeating the values of the cycle before matlab?

Tags: matlab

hey I'm doing a biomechanical model of the L2 vertebra and I have found a problem which I had problems solving.

```
count = 0; 
for ii = 1:num_g 
    for jj = idx(ii) 
        if id(jj) >= -1 & count <= dimension 
            count = count + 1; 
            S_ef_equivalent(1,count) = S_ef(1,jj); 
            minidx(1,count) = jj; 
        end 
    end
end
```

I have this part of code where is going to pick up the values with the lowest density and remodel the bone and it works but the code after running a cycle of 3 times stops evolving and don't remodel the rest of the plate ( wich will give me the RX of a bone ). So my question is how can I solve this problem.
How can I make a cycle without repeating the point from the cycle used before?

thanks

Comment: What's `idx` and `id`?

Comment: idx is the index of the lowest density points of the plate...and id>=-1 it will pick up all the values bigger then 0.1 g/cm^3

Comment: I am a little lost in your terminology, but would a blacklist (index) with visited points do the trick?